# Find partial text in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel 2013 I would like to find the value in column B in the row where a string matches a string in column A. What complicates it is that the strings in column A are allowed to be shorter than the value string sought. Example:

```
Column A    Column B
ABCD-       Result1
EF          Result2
BCD         Result3
```

Now, examples of strings that should return...

```
"Result1": "ABCD-", "ABCD-EFG", "ABCD-H"
"Result2": "EF", "EFG", "EFGHIIJKL"
"Result3": "BCD", "BCDXY"
```

"ABCD" should not return any result.

Assume the sought string is in cell C1.

Do I have to resort to a macro or is there a formula for this?

**UPD**:
There will be several sought strings that will actually be located in a column on another sheet and there will not be any wildcards at the beginning. The value I am looking for could be placed in the column next to the column with sought strings.

**UPD2**:
Assume Column A and Column B content on Sheet1 and the content on Sheet2 below:

```
SoughtString    ResultFound
ABCD-           Result1
EF              Result2
BCD             Result3
BCDXY           Result3
EFG             Result2
ABCD-EFG        Result1
EFGHIIJKL       Result2
ABCD-H          Result1
ABCD            No match
```

Having the slightly modified array formula from the accepted answer in cell B2 copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B$2:B$4;MATCH(1;COUNTIF(A2;Sheet1!A$2:A$4&"*")*(Sheet1!A$2:A$4<>"");0));"No match")
```

Comment: You want to basically do a vlookup with a value that won't exactly match the lookup array? Will there be strings in Col A that may start with the same sequence of characters? Will the sequence you are looking up always match the string starting at the first character?

Comment: MBWise - it looks like three people have interpreted you question in three different ways.  Can you clarify what you're looking for?  If one of the solutions is already the answer, click on the checkmark.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I have tried to clarify my question and accepted the answer from barry houdini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have data in rows 2 to 10 you can use this "array formula"

`=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$10,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(C1,A$2:A$10&"*")*(A$2:A$10<>""),0)),"No match")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Clever with the wildcard on the range parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what role C1 plays.  If the sought strings already exist in a column, you can use that as what you show as Col A of Sheet2.  If they are somewhere else you can build Col A by just referencing the associated cell in the other list.  For example, if the list is in Col Z, starting in row 2, A2 would be `=Z2`, and you could copy that formula down Col A to pre-populate more cells than you need (these will remain blank until needed).

If the sought string list is being created one new entry at a time, you could just place the new entries in the next position in either list (Col Z or Col A).  If the new entries must go into C1 and each new entry replaces the one before, you would need a macro or VBA program to build the list from the C1 entries.

Starting from the point where the sought strings will be in a list in Col A via any of these methods, this is what would go in Col B.  Assume Result1 is in B2.  The formula in B2 would be:

```
    =IF(ISERROR(FIND(Sheet1!A2,A2)),"NO MATCH",IF(FIND(Sheet1!A2,A2)=1,A2,"NO MATCH"))
```

Copy the formula down column B for as many as you need.  You can pre-populate Col B with an arbitrary large number of entries and these will remain blank until there is a value in the associated cell in Col A that produces a result.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. See my updated question. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Your clarification left me more confused than before.  You would really need to show an example for someone else to understand the problem.  Since you already got a solution, decide how much effort you want to put in to making the question useful for others or to attract additional solutions.

Comment: See UPD2 for an example.

Comment: Is the difference from my formula that you want to build the list of C1 values down col A and show the corresponding result in col B?

Comment: Yes, I want the results listed with the sought strings. In my original question (without updates), I would want the result in D1.